# How to run unit tests with IDEA+Gradle+Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, gradle-android-test-plugi, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I've written some unit tests in my Android projects with [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/), and some of them even don't use Android.

I've tried first this: [robolectric-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin), following [this template](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle).
The result is that I've faced [this bug in IDEA](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127247), that I reported myself.

Then I've tried another possibility: the [gradle-android-test-plugin](https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-test-plugin), which separates tests in another submodule, that is a regular Java project.  I've tried to follow this [other template](https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template).  I've open this [bug report](https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template/issues/12).

Then I've faced again with [other bug](https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-test-plugin/issues/10).

What recommendations can you provide me, that does work?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've had to upgrade IDEA to 14 EAP, and know it works ok.

gradle-android-test-plugin seems to work better than robolectric plugin, as I can run JUnit and ScalaTest tests easily.  I've had to install with a script, the non-published com.novoda:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.9-SNAPSHOT.

It's a hell the combination of versions of:

- Android Build Tools
- Gradle
- com.android.tools.build:gradle
- IDEA
- robolectric
- robolectric plugin
- ....

Any change in one of them, can make your project fail.

Luckily, by using Gradle you can fix the versions of every component, and do Continous integration.